Find any spanning tree that covers a subgraph of a directed graph
We have a business use case that basically boils down to the following CS problem:
Given a directed graph F and a subset of vertices / subgraph G = v1, v2, ... , vk we want to find any tree T that spans G (i.e. all of v1, v2, ... , vk are all vertices of T) and its root.
To give you an example, given following graph F,

G = {
plan_description,
person_id (+ temporal condition on effective_date | submission_date},
benefit_code
},
the algorithm should output the tree that looks like

and return person_id (+ temporal condition on effective_date | submission_date} as the root.
For context, we are thinking about building a visual query language over our Data Lake that allows users to ask for a sink column (e.g. plan_id) subject to conditions on other columns (e.g. benefit_code = MED). We want to identify the root of this spanning tree so that we can determine the join order for the SQL that we need to generate. In this example, that join order would be:

Do a join from the orange to the red table.
Do a join from ^ to the green table.

or

Do a join from the orange to the green table
Do a join from ^ to the red table

Does this abstraction fit into a well-studied problem archetype?

What is the criteria for choosing the root? Trees can be rooted arbitrarily.

@Unmitigated the intent is to begin joining from the table that the root node belongs to

Finding a spanning tree in a DIRECTED graph is tricky.  In your sample output I can see no vertex that can serve as a root, mostly because the orange vertex has an in-degree of zero - it is unreachable from all the other vertices.  Perhaps you do not really care about the edge directions - in which case just copy the subgraph to the equivalent undirected graph and apply Pim's algorithm.

@ravenspoint I think that if it is possible, my answer will succeed in finding that tree. Can you check my reasoning and see if you agree?

This will start with what looks like a detour, but isn't.
In Converting cyclic DiGraph to Acyclic DiGraph (DAG) I show how to convert a cyclic graph into an acyclic graph by doing a topological sort, greedily removing as few edges as I can at every point to do so. The algorithm is quite efficient, even on fairly large graphs.
But I'm greedily removing as few edges as I can. If the original graph is connected, at no step will it get disconnected. Because disconnecting it requires removing more edges than necessary.
Therefore if the original graph is connected, then so must be the resulting acyclic graph. Better yet, the acyclic graph arrives topologically sorted. Therefore we know the root that must be the root of the tree (if any).
Now an acyclic graph is not a tree. But you can make it into a tree by deleting all but one incoming edge for every vertex. Since you are attempting to do a query on a data lake, I would suggest that you not just randomly delete those edges. Instead prune it on something like a cardinality estimate for your join. But that's something that you can play with to figure out what works best for you.
I'm sorry for not noticing this problem for a few days. Hopefully a late answer is still useful for you.
